# Responsive Elements in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

Hi im having trouble and could really use some help.

I'm using Visual Composer for Wordpress and the free Spacious theme to build my site and I have used custom css to move the navbar, fb logo and brochure/pdf icon.

The fb and brochure/pdf icon are 2 raw html elements at the bottom of the page and i gave them classes and moved all the elements, navbar,fb logo,pdf logo, product categories title manually using css

But whenever you zoom in or shrink the screen, or hover on the dropdowns on the images they jump somewhere else, can someone tell me how to make them all responsive so it looks good on all screen sizes, even mobile without the jumping?

Or does anyone know an easier way to do it? i didn't know any other way to get them at those spots.

site: http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/

*Edit: dropdown solved but not the shrinking screen part*

Heres my css

```
.main-navigation {
padding-right; 5px;
}
.main-navigation a {
color: black;
position: relative;
top: -35px;
right: 200px;
} 

.fbicon {
position:relative;
top: -845px;
right: -1200px; 
}

.pdficon {
position:relative;
top: -695px;
right: -1190px;
}

.pdficontext {
position:relative;
top: -650px;
right: -1070px;
color: #0e4776;
font-weight: bold;
}

.contactusheader {
position:relative;
top: -980px;
}

.productcategoriestitle {
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu's are positioned relative, so they mess up the lay-out when they appear.

If you would make them absolute, no other element will be affected.

So you could try to change the position of the dropdowns. Ad z-index to make them appear on top of the footer.

```
.dropdown-content 
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: That works nicely thanks :) any ideas how i can fix the navbar,fb logo and pdf from moving when you shrink the screen? before: http://1drv.ms/i/s!AvSBx9lkGZr3gdYAFLed1ANk662kOA after: http://1drv.ms/i/s!AvSBx9lkGZr3gdYBrERfRoRLXkWhrA